# how to hide a td like acordian in jquery

Tags: javascript, html

i have a table which is as follows:

left side it has has got menu listed and top is the logo and right is the actual content like listing the data and so on.

now i want to hide the menu when user clicks on and enable when the clicks on the same again.

how to do this in java script?

below is the image for sample :

[image]

Comment: Please show your actual mark-up, not a picture of the output of the mark-up.

Comment: thanks for the comment, see my answer it works as i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped me to achieve what i wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell">
            Some info
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Show/hide" />
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
     $("#cell").toggle();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

Online demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/DVxSy/